# Importing Local Files in Python

Tags: python

Here is my file structure (well, part of it):

```
server.py
model > eval.py
        arch.json
        weights.h5
```

`eval.py` has a function in it that uses `arch.json` and `weights.h5` through the paths "arch.json", "weights.h5".
I want to include `eval.py` in `server.py`, but that means the view point becomes the directory of `server.py`.
Is there any way I can tell `eval.py` to look at paths from his own viewpoint, so that the function would work no matter who calls it?

Comment: Can you tell what approach you have taken and what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: @bumblebee I tried to use the relative import that every python 2.6+ (I think) has (I am using python 3.7.2). I just wrote "from model import eval", and it does include the file. Problem is, that all paths are measured from the server.py file, including paths inside eval.py's code. That means I have to use "model/arch.json", for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that there are a number of ways of looking at the executing path, e.g.

```
__file__, 
os.path.abspath(__file__) and 
inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()),
```

These can be applied to an imported module, e.g.

```
eval.__file__, 
os.path.abspath(eval.__file__)
inspect.getfile(eval).
```

Perhaps you could try these out to work out what action you would like to take based upon these values.   I do believe the `__file__` changes based upon if you are executing from the current script or if the function is imported, so it might be worth being careful with that.